# readmore javascript plugin first item open

Tags: javascript

I'm using this wonderful plugin and would like to know how I can set the first item to be open and the rest closed.

Any idea?

**Javascript**

```
var options = {
            moreLink: '<a class="read_more_link" href="#">more...</a>',
            lessLink: '<a class="read_less_link" href="#">less...</a>',
            heightMargin: 50,
            sectionCSS: 'display: inline-block; width: 100%;',
        };

    $('.content-top-wide, .content-bottom-item').each(function(){
        var el = $(this), content = el.find('div:first,span:first,p:first, article:first'), maxHeight = 0;
        if (content.length) {
            maxHeight = content.outerHeight();
            content.prevAll().each(function(){
                maxHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
            });
            // set maxHeight to 200px  if the element has hight greater than 200  
            options.maxHeight = Math.min(200, maxHeight);
            el.readmore(options);
        };
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="content-bottom pull-left">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="content-bottom-item pull-left">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, consequatur inventore iure aliquam praesentium molestiae facilis labore! Magni, dolorem, ex? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, consequatur inventore iure aliquam praesentium molestiae facilis labore! Magni, dolorem, ex?
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed doing this by adding an if statement:

```
if ( i == 0) {
                options.startOpen = true;
            } else {
                options.startOpen = false;
            }
            el.readmore(options);
```

Here is a working version in case someone need: http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/pvZ8H/

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of the plugin: https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js ?
Adding "startOpen: false" to the options of the first item should solve your problem.

Comment: I've already read the documentation and that is exactly what I am trying to know how to do - Adding "startOpen: false" to the options of the first item.

Their documentation explain how to add the startOpen: false to all items but not for the first one.